# Angular HttpClient Object to Array

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have an HttpClient call in Angular 6 that responds with a single object but what I need is an Array. How can I convert the single object returned by the service into an Array that has the single object in it?

I've tried the tap and map operators in Rxjs but think I am missing something simple somewhere. Code is below:

```
  search(): Observable<TrainInfo[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<TrainInfo[]>(this.SEARCH_URL)
      .pipe(
        // ??? Something here to convert TrainInfo object returned by get into TrainInfo[]
      );
  }
```

TLDR: search_url returns one object (TrainInfo), actually need Array (TrainInfo[])

Comment: Does `search_url` ALWAYS return one `TrainInfo` or can it return one or multiple?

Comment: Did you try `pipe(map(trainInfo => [trainInfo]))`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map is the operator you were looking for. If `search_url` always returns a single `TrainInfo`, this should do the trick:

```js
search(): Observable<TrainInfo[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<TrainInfo>(this.SEARCH_URL)
    .pipe(
      map(value => [ value ]));
}
```